# React Native app running on Expo Go - compatible Google / Facebook Login method not found

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, facebook-authentication, expo-go

I am working on Google / Facebook login on my React Native app with Expo Go. I have tried the following methods but none of them can work on my app and I am writing to ask if there is any other method I can try on:

1. Firebase SDK:
   I tried using the web modular API (since my React Native app running on Expo Go is sort of a web-like app?) but then I found out this cannot work, since React Native does not export the signInWIthPopup and signInWithReactNative entrypoints since both of these functions directly modify the DOM.
2. react-native-firebase and expo-auth-session
   Then I tried these two libraries, however, following the latest documents of the packages/libraries, all of them don't support app running on Expo Go due to the custom native code thing... The deprecated methods might work in my case but again, they're deprecated...

So currently I'm kind of stuck on this situation. I wonder if there is any other method I can try on, which is compatible with my framework. Or the only way to solve this problem is that I need to implement the development build of my app?

Thanks in advance and I am looking forward to any advice~!